# Why prompted "no viable alternative" error in Apache IoTDB when trying to activate aligned time series template?

Tags: apache-iotdb, iotdb

When I activate aligned time series template in Apache IoTDB, the system prompted that `no viable alternative at input 'create timeseries using'`. Have any of you encountered this problem and how to solve it?